# css - draw 2 squares side by side and each with a circle in the center

Tags: css

I'm trying out a css challenge where the requirements state that:

- Draw 2 squares of width 50px side by side
- Each square should have a circle in the center with width of 10px
- The distance between two squares should be 10px

I can't seem to make my circle appear.. Here's my fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/xmozvs5p/

Here's a snippet of my css:

```
  .square {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
  }
  .circle{
    background-color:green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:10px;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    }
```

Comment: Add height to the inside `.circle`

Comment: @yomisimie - how silly! Yes, I did that. However, my circle is still not centered.

Comment: To center it vertically, add margins to it. You could even use `margin: calc((50px - 10px) / 2) auto`. That means that `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` will be 50px (the height of the square) - 10px (circle) divided by 2 (the 2 sides, top and bottom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a height to the `.circle` element and it can be centered using flexbox on the parent.

```css
.square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px 5px; /* 10px between elements */
}

.circle {
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
<div class="square">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this way with less of code:

```css
.square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  background:radial-gradient(circle at center,green 5px,transparent 6px);
  margin: 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
</div>
<div class="square">
</div>
```